# Angular перерендер таблицы

Tags: angular

Есть таблица, из Material библиотеки которая подключена к WebSocket и получает данные в среднем раз в 500мс. Все данные в колонке - динамические, значения любого столбца как и кол-во строк могут измениться в любой момент.

Проблема. В таблице появилась кнопка, а так как она все время перерендеривается, то и кнопка вместе с ней, в результате она срабатывает через раз:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="rows">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="empty">
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
      <span>Пусто</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="percent">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Процент </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{ row.percent }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Закрыть </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button
        (click)="closeDialog(element)"
        mat-mini-fab color="warn">
        <mat-icon style="color: white">
          disabled_by_default
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="!rows.length ? ['empty'] : []" class="empty"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

WebSocket получает все состояние таблицы целиком и целиком присваивает весь массив

```
this.streamService
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.rows = data.items;
  });
```

Какие есть возможные пути решения данной проблемы?

Comment: удалить плохую кнопку и вставить свою хорошую.

Comment: @Zombotron Не понял. Перерисовывается то вся строка таблицы, без разницы какая там кнопка будет.

Comment: Если без разницы, то в чем проблема с ее несрабатыванием?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы уменьшить число DOM операций, можно добавить в input `mat-table` функцию `trackBy`. Как минимум те строки, которые не обновились не будут рендериться на каждый чих.

Но проблема явно внутри бизнес-логики. Рендер строк раз в полсекунды - это прям беда. Как минимум закрывай все диалоги, когда приходят новые данные. Вот прям в подписке. Тогда не будет вопросов, что клик хендлер сработает для элемента, которого уже может не быть.

Comment: `Как минимум закрывай все диалоги` про это (click)="closeDialog(element)"? не это диалог подтверждения действия по кнопке, до него то и не доходит правильно. Ну проблема в том что таблица по сути как realtime график используется, причем динамически меняется не только последний элемент но все сразу  Можно сравнить с графиком-эквалайзером звука.

Comment: суть в том, что подход в лоб (добавить кнопочку) на таких быстро меняющихся данных - это не совсем адекватно. Простой кейс, пользователь хочет нажать твою кнопку по элементу с id=1, а там все быстро в таблице поменялось, и он нажимает уже на id=2. В таких таблицах (эквалайзер и тп) обычно нет действий. Это ридонли информация. Поэтому думайте че с UX.

Comment: выкрутился. Построил рядом еще одну таблицу с одной колонкой с кнопкой и перерисовываю только когда кол-во строк меняется.